# Writing to a text file by a method that takes in a string parameter

Tags: java

Hi guys, I'm trying to pass in a string parameter to write that string to a text file.
However , I seem to be having trouble. It works fine when I compile it in a main method, it creates a file and all the values that I write into it. 
However, when I use a method. It doesn't create a file at all, not even with the parameters that i passed in. I am intending to use the method in a servlet.

Below is the method that I created.

```
public class testWriteFile {
    public static void writeToFile (String data) throws Exception {
        Date dateNow = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        StringBuilder formatDDMMYYYY = new StringBuilder(sdf.format(dateNow));

        File file = new File(formatDDMMYYYY+".txt");

        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

May I know what is the problem with the code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the java verson?

Comment: the version is 1.7.0_25

Comment: Looks OK to me. You don't need to create the file first but it does not hurt. Are you sure the method is called (i.e. do you see the "Done" output)?

Comment: yes i do see the done output. However no file was created.

Comment: Where do you expect to see the file ? Is it in the same directory from which the program was executed ?

Comment: it should be in C:\Users\Larry\Desktop\Java\MyServletProject as i tested it out with a main method at first. It will be created there

Comment: Are you using an IDE ? Can you search across all directories for  the filename in `MyServletProject` ? May be the IDE has its own bin folder where it is created.

Comment: yes i am using an IDE i searched across all the directories in MyServletProject. However, there is no such file

Comment: OK, debugging tip : Print `System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath())`. That is the location of your file.

Comment: thanks bsd . i was looking in the wrong folder, it looks like that file got created at my eclipse folder . OMG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, seems like the issue was resolved when the OP printed

```
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

It was in a different directory since the OP was using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

use a full path ("d:/myfolder/a.txt") - can still keep part of it dynamic like if windows

```
File f = new File("D:/myfolder/" + formatDDMMYYYY + ".txt");
```

Or linux/ mac

```
File f = new File("/myfolder/" + formatDDMMYYYY + ".txt");
```

Make sure you have write permission on the myfolder and replace it with one you do have by using touch command on linux/ unix like systems in terminal :

```
touch /myfolder/a.txt
ls -l /myfolder/a.txt
```

Should show current date for that file